# How to get an element with specific value from firestore array?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and app development in general.

I had a code to fetch a document from firestore using streambuilder and would like to build a chat tile using the data. I found myself stuck trying to get the chat partner username since I saved it in an array and both users use the same document. To get a better idea, here's a screenshot of my firestore document:

[image: firestore collection of chatRoom]

To solve this problem I cast the `List<dynamic>` of usersName from the document snapshot to `List<String>` and call another method to check the value of each element one by one and return the string that is different from the current user name.

The code works fine, but I feel like there's a better way to do this.
I'd be grateful if you can give me **suggestions on better solutions**!

Here is the stream builder code:

```
  chatList() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: chatRooms,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        return snapshot.hasData
          ? SingleChildScrollView(
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return ChatTile(
                  chatRoomId: snapshot.data.docs[index].data()["chatRoomId"], 
                  contactName: getContactName(List<String>
                      .from(snapshot.data.docs[index].data()['usersName'] as List))
                      .toString(),
                  recentMessageText: 'test', 
                  contactImagePath: '', 
                  recentMessageTime: 1680069876235, 
                  isRead: false);
              }),
          )
          : noChatHistory();
      }
    );
  }
```

and here is the method I used to find the chat partner username:

```
getContactName(List<String> nameList) {
  var targetUserName = StringBuffer();

  nameList.forEach((element) {
    if (element != currentUserName) {
      targetUserName.write(element);
    }
  });
    
  return targetUserName.toString();
}
```

Comment: Please do not post images of plaintext as [they are not appropriate on StackOverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3784008). Please copy and paste plaintext into your question.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on your particular use case, but if more than 2 users can join a chat room, then what I would suggest is to change the model of the `ChatRoom` document.

Instead of having separate properties for `users` and `usersName`, you could have one property, I would call it participants and use the following structure:

```json
"participants": {
  "b8ctqymu9gfDW5pnPu7pXQApWSp2": {
    "name": "Siti Ainun",
    "uid": "b8ctqymu9gfDW5pnPu7pXQApWSp2"
  },
  "655gEbHcGrVjKHLIh7iMt9Kadog2": {
    "name": "Tester Account 2",
    "uid": "655gEbHcGrVjKHLIh7iMt9Kadog2"
}
```

In this way, you can then easily fetch all of the conversations where a user belong and also get the other user in the conversation by filtering values of the map.